# How to configure FxCop in SonarQube 6.2

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sonarqube, fxcop

I am having hard time while trying to configure FxCop with SonarQube 6.2 along with TFS Continuous Integration Build 2015.

I could able to successfully configure TFS build definition with SonarQube 6.2  and it is running perfectly fine but couldn't able to integrate FxCop into it.

I couldn't able to find any plugin for FxCop in the SonarQube website and also, most of the viable solutions available in the internet for FxCop integration with SonarQube along with TFS Build definition are deprecated for SonarQube version 6.2.

Note: I am using Visual Studio 2015 and SonarQube 6.2 and VS is already instilled in our build server and i could able to find the FxCop .exe file in
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Update on the matter: it seems that the community started building a dedicated plugin. I haven't tested it out though. https://github.com/DanielHWe/sonar-fxcop/

Comment: @Raj, As baywet said [this plugin](https://github.com/DanielHWe/sonar-fxcop/) works well for my usecase.

Answer (score 0):

You can see FxCop is deprecated in SonarQube, and there is no document to specify how to configure it in SonarQube now:

[image]