# Are Fxcop & StyleCop not required for latest Sonarqube 6.2 ?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

Are fxcop and stylecop not required for sonarqube scanner in 6.2 version for C# analysis? Earlier version ( probably 5.1 ), I had installed both the tools before I setup MSBuildSonar runner.  IN latest version , I don't see any where about them. Below post also mentions same. If Fxcop is not used, Who is responsible for code analysis?

[Fxcop in Sonarqube6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125384/how-to-configure-fxcop-in-sonarqube-6-2)

Any insight on this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

6.2 comes pre-loaded with SonarC#, which provides metrics and rules for C#. It will handle the analysis for you.